# Creating and loading views with storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I am quite new to iOS development and thus new to the concept of `storyboard` as well.
As this seems to be the 'new thing', everyone should use, I thought I might give it a try as well.

I got a project here, created with a `Foo.xib` file.

The `xib` file has several `view` objects included.

Then I have a class `Foo.h` and `Foo.m` class with following content:

`Foo.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Foo : UIView
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *view01;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *view02;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *view03;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *view04;

- (NSUInteger)viewCount;

@end
```

`Foo.m`

```
#import "Foo.h"

@interface Foo()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *views;
@end

@implementation Foo

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Foo" owner:self options:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSUInteger)viewCount {
    return [self.views count];
}

@end
```

In my `ViewController` I would then load all the views and make it scrollable, like this:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Foo.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Foo *views;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.views = [[Foo alloc] init];
    CGSize fooSize = self.views.view01.bounds.size;
    NSUInteger viewCount = [self.views viewCount];
    self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, fooSize.width, fooSize.height)];
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(viewCount*fooSize.width, fooSize.height)];
    [self.scrollView setBounces:YES];
    [self.scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;

    NSArray *views = @[ self.views.view01,
                        self.views.view02,
                        self.views.view03,
                        self.views.view04
                      ];

    for (int i=0; i<viewCount; i++) {
        UIView *curView = views[i];
        CGRect frame = curView.frame;
        frame.origin.x = i*fooSize.width;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        curView.frame = frame;
        [self.scrollView addSubview:curView];
    }

    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

However, I have no clue, how to realize this with a storyboard. It seems to me that I have to have a `NavigationController` which is then linked to the `Master View Controller`. And now I would have to add a new `ViewController` for each view? Or is there a way to include all views within one `ViewController` like I did 'the old way'?

Comment: don't forget to upvote / mark as top answer if my answer has solved your question. otherwise leave some additional comments / questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a massive mis conception that when using a storyboard it limits you to what you can do. A storyboard is simply like an array of .xib files, it holds many screens in the one file so you can see the entire flow of you app in one place. Inside a storyboard you can create a single viewController and assign a custom viewController class to it and then load / modify what ever you like inside the code of this viewController, as you have done above.

However the benefit of using the storyboard is to have multiple viewController objects so you can design all the screens and navigation there were you can see it, aiding you in debugging and design work.

If you already have the app working without a storyboard and you simply want to use it because its new but keep the old style of coding, you are not going to see much of the benefits. I would suggest following this example from the developer library on how to use a storyboard properly. After you complete this you will see the benefits of the new style and you can decide whether to do it in code or using the interface builder:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011318